Include SCSS files in TSUP build of Lit Library
I want to include SCSS files that I have in my Lit Library in the build. I build my library using TSUP.
However, whenever I try to do this, I get a No loader is configured for ".scss" error.
Below is the full error:
CLI Building entry: ./src/index.ts, ./src/components/button/button.ts, ./src/main.scss
CLI Using tsconfig: ../../tsconfig.json
CLI tsup v8.0.2
CLI Using tsup config: /Users/{my-name}/Documents/Repositories/{our-repo-name}/projects/transform-design-system/tsup.config.js
CLI Target: es2022,node18
CLI Cleaning output folder
CJS Build start
ESM Build start
✘ [ERROR] No loader is configured for ".scss" files: src/main.scss

✘ [ERROR] No loader is configured for ".scss" files: src/main.scss

CJS Build failed
Error: Build failed with 1 error:
error: No loader is configured for ".scss" files: src/main.scss
    at failureErrorWithLog (/Users/{my-name}/Documents/Repositories/{our-repo-name}/node_modules/tsup/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1651:15)
    at /Users/{my-name}/Documents/Repositories/{our-repo-name}/node_modules/tsup/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1059:25
    at runOnEndCallbacks (/Users/{my-name}/Documents/Repositories/{our-repo-name}/node_modules/tsup/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1486:45)
    at buildResponseToResult (/Users/{my-name}/Documents/Repositories/{our-repo-name}/node_modules/tsup/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1057:7)
    at /Users/{my-name}/Documents/Repositories/{our-repo-name}/node_modules/tsup/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1086:16
    at responseCallbacks.<computed> (/Users/{my-name}/Documents/Repositories/{our-repo-name}/node_modules/tsup/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:704:9)
    at handleIncomingPacket (/Users/{my-name}/Documents/Repositories/{our-repo-name}/node_modules/tsup/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:764:9)
    at Socket.readFromStdout (/Users/{my-name}/Documents/Repositories/{our-repo-name}/node_modules/tsup/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:680:7)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:517:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:368:12)
ESM Build failed
DTS Build start
DTS ⚡️ Build success in 2196ms
DTS dist/main.d.cts                     13.00 B
DTS dist/components/button/button.d.cts 638.00 B
DTS dist/index.d.cts                    90.00 B
DTS dist/main.d.ts                      13.00 B
DTS dist/components/button/button.d.ts  638.00 B
DTS dist/index.d.ts                     89.00 B

How do I setup a loader for this in the TSUP config?
Here is my current config:
import { defineConfig } from "tsup";

export default defineConfig({
  entry: ["./src/index.ts", "./src/components/button/button.ts", "./src/main.scss"],
  format: ["cjs", "esm"],
  target: ["es2022", "node18"],
  outDir: "dist",
  dts: true,
  sourcemap: true,
  clean: true
});

This Lit library is released as a NPM pkg. If it helps I'm on Node 18 and using TSUP version 8.0.2, which is the latest (I believe).
Also, this error happens even when I don't include the scss file in the entry property array of the TSUP config. If my Lit component uses any scss file, it still gets the same error.

Were you able to solve this?

Under the hood tsup uses esbuild which doesn't have sass support. You need to install esbuild-sass-plugin as dev dependencies:
npm i esbuild-sass-plugin -D
# Or Yarn
yarn add esbuild-sass-plugin --dev

Then in your tsup.config.ts use it to transform your scss files:
import { sassPlugin } from 'esbuild-sass-plugin';
import { defineConfig } from "tsup";

export default defineConfig({
  entry: ["./src/index.ts", "./src/components/button/button.ts", "./src/main.scss"],
  format: ["cjs", "esm"],
  target: ["es2022", "node18"],
  outDir: "dist",
  dts: true,
  sourcemap: true,
  clean: true,
  esbuildPlugins: [
    sassPlugin({
       type: 'lit-css'
    })
  ]
});

